# Startup and shutdown DB Oracle in preset time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How I can preset time startup and shutdown DB Oracle ? Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you know how to start it up and shut it down, create two scripts (if on MS Windows, these would be .BAT files). Test whether they work correctly.

Then, using Task Scheduler, *schedule* the STARTUP.BAT to run in the morning and SHUTDOWN.BAT to run in the afternoon (or whenever you want).